# How to run Asm.js In IE11, getting legacy_vm_support problem

Tags: webassembly, asm.js

I complied `faac.c` and `opus.c` to `asm.js`. When I run `asm.js` in IE11, it throws an error message:

```
this is a legacy browser build with legacy_vm_support
```

I do not know whether IE11 support asm.js and how to work in IE11?

I complied faac.c and opus.c to asm.js. asm.js can run in edge、chrome and so on, but IE11 does not work, again:

```
this is a legacy browser build with legacy_vm_support
```

Comment: [A quick Google search](https://caniuse.com/#feat=asmjs) seems to suggest IE11 does not support asm.js out of the box. Maybe a polyfill exists?

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://emscripten.org/docs/introducing_emscripten/release_notes.html), from version `v1.38.1: 05/17/2018` you have to compile your code with `-s LEGACY_VM_SUPPORT=1` to make it work in old browsers.

> Breaking change: Emit WebAssembly by default. Only the default is changed -
>      we of course still support asm.js, and will for a very long time. But
>      changing the default makes sense as the recommended output for most use cases
>      should be WebAssembly, given it has shipped in all major browsers and
>      platforms and is more efficient than asm.js. Build with `-s WASM=0` to
>      disable wasm and use asm.js if you want that (or use `-s LEGACY_VM_SUPPORT=1`, which emits output that can run in older browsers,
>      which includes a bunch of polyfills as well as disables wasm). (#6419)